# Caching at QuerySet level in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to get a queryset from the cache, but am unsure if this even has a point.

I have the following method (simplified) inside a **custom queryset**:

```
    def queryset_from_cache(self, key: str=None, timeout: int=60):
        # Generate a key based on the query.
        if key is None:
            key = self.__generate_key # ()

        # If the cache has the key, return the cached object.
        cached_object = cache.get(key, None)

        # If the cache doesn't have the key, set the cache, 
        # and then return self (from DB) as cached_object
        if cached_object is None:
            cached_object = self
            cache.set(key, cached_object , timeout=timeout)

        return cached_object
```

The usage is basically to append it to a django QuerySet method, for example:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id__range=[0,99]).queryset_from_cache()
```

---

##### My question:

Would usage like this work?

Or would it call `MyModel.objects.filter(id__range=[0,99])` from the database no matter  what?

---

###### Since normally caching would be done like this:

```
cached_object = cache.get(key, None)

if cached_object is None:
    cached_object = MyModel.objects.filter(id__range=[0,99])
    #Only now call the query
    cache.set(key, cached_object , timeout=timeout)
```

And thus the queryset `filter()` method only gets called when the key is not present in the cache, as opposed to always calling it, and then trying to get it from the cache with the `queryset_from_cache` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really cool idea, but <s>I'm not sure if you can Cache full-on Objects.. I think it's only attributes</s>

Now this having a **point.** Grom what I'm seeing from the limited code I've seen idk if it does have a point, unless filtering for Jane and John (and only them) is very common. Very *narrow*.
Maybe just try caching ALL the users or just individual Users, and only the attributes you need

---

### Update

Yes! you are completetly correct, you **can** cache full on objects- how cool!

I don't think your example method of `queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id__range=[0,99]).queryset_from_cache()` would work.

but you can do something similar by using Model Managers and do something like: `queryset = MyModel.objects.queryset_from_cache(filterdict)`

#### Models

- Natually you can return *just* the qs, this is just for the example to show it actually is from the cache

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
  def queryset_from_cache(self, filterdict):
    from django.core.cache import cache

    cachekey = 'MyModelCache'
    qs = cache.get(cachekey)

    if qs:
      d = {
        'in_cache': True,
        'qs': qs
        }
    else:
      qs = MyModel.objects.filter(**filterdict)
      cache.set(cachekey, qs, 300) # 5 min cache
      d = {
        'in_cache': False,
        'qs': qs
        }
    return d


class MyModel(models.Model):
  name    =   models.CharField(max_length=200)
  #
  # other attributes
  #

  objects = MyModelManager()
```

#### Example Use

```py
from app.models import MyModel
filterdict = {'pk__range':[0,99]}
r = MyModel.objects.queryset_from_cache(filterdict)
print(r['qs'])
```

While it's not exactly what you wanted, it might be close enough

Comment: Updated my question. This isn't specifically for users, but is more of a generalized method which I'm intending to use on multiple models, not specifically a user model. Caching whole objects is perfectly possible. You can cache most logic, objects, and even stuff like templates or files.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I don't think it's exactly what you want, but it might be close enough to be usable.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way, but this wont allow me to generate query-specific cache keys. I appreciate the help, and you've still answered my question on wether this would be possible. Have a great day!